# Same space between matplotlib plot labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have different values that don't have the same space between them, here's an example :

```py
1     0.01027   0.00658   0.01341    0.02485    ...etc
2     0.00421   0.00350   0.00391    0.00456    ...etc
3     0.00419   0.00344   0.00351    0.00387    ...etc
4     0.00417   0.00342   0.00342    0.00359    ...etc
5     0.00414   0.00327   0.00336    0.00348    ...etc
6     0.00411   0.00302   0.00332    0.00340    ...etc
7     0.00404   0.00298   0.00328    0.00332    ...etc
8     0.00393   0.00296   0.00325    0.00324    ...etc
9     0.00391   0.00295   0.00322    0.00319    ...etc
10    0.00391   0.00294   0.00320    0.00316    ...etc
11    0.00391   0.00294   0.00317    0.00313    ...etc
12    0.00391   0.00293   0.00315    0.00311    ...etc
13    0.00391   0.00293   0.00312    0.00309    ...etc
14    0.00391   0.00293   0.00310    0.00308    ...etc
15    0.00391   0.00293   0.00308    0.00306    ...etc
16    0.00391   0.00293   0.00307    0.00305    ...etc
17    0.00391   0.00293   0.00305    0.00303    ...etc
18    0.00391   0.00292   0.00303    0.00302    ...etc
19    0.00391   0.00292   0.00302    0.00301    ...etc
20    0.00391   0.00292   0.00301    0.00300    ...etc
```

When i plot them in matplotlib by doing :

```py
plt.plot(COL_0, COL_1)
plt.plot(COL_0, COL_2)
plt.plot(COL_0, COL_3)
plt.plot(COL_0, COL_4)
...etc
```

I get the following plot :

[image: plot 1]

How do i force a constant spacing between ticks (without respecting the values) so that the plots are clearer like this :

[image: plot 2]

Thank you !

Comment: you could just try `plt.xlim([6, 20]); plt.ylim([0.00275, 0.005)` ? As I see it, yoiur problem does not have to do with ticks but with axis limits.

Comment: @cripcate i want to keep all the values but change the space between them to have a better plot visually.

Comment: I don’t really get what you mean? `plt.xlim` adjusts the x axis limits but your data will all still be there. (Just some of it out of bounds of the figure). What about a logarithmic scale? I don’t think you want to alter your data all together do you?

Comment: @cripcate I want to keep the data all in the figure, but change the distance (just in the figure) between the ticks so that they look better ... like I showed in the 2nd plot .. (I don't want data to be not visible like in the second plot, it's just not visible because there was no other way for me to explain what I need )

Answer (score 0):

How to limit the numbers to be plotted

```
ax.plot(df.index[5:], df.loc[6:,'32'], label='32')
```

How to extend the range of the x-axis to the right

```
ax.set_xlim(−5, 20)
```

Comment: I don't want to limit the plotted data .. I would like to be able to change the space between them to make the figure more readable.